# Matlab how to find boundary submatrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

let a and b are sequence of k consecutive natural numbers a = (a_i) and b = (b_i). If A an n x n matrix, then A[a,b] (a nontrivial submatrix of A which is obtained from eliminating elements that doesnt belong in rows a and columns b) is called boundary submatrix if

i) a_1 = 1 or a_1 > 1 and A[(a_1 - 1),b] = 0

or

ii) b_1 = 1 or b_1 > 1 and A[a,(b_1 - 1)] = 0
(yes the matrix usually got some zero entries)
what is the easiest code to understand for this case?

I tried to make and array for the sequence using columnk but it seems difficult.

Example for matrix

```
B =

 1     1     1     0
 1     2     1     1
 0     1     2     2
 0     0     3     2
```

if we pick a = 2,3 and b = 3,4 we get

```
B(a,b) = 
 1     1
 2     2
```

and the example of its boundary submatrices of B would be its every principal submatrix, and B([2,3],[2,3]) since B([2,3],1)=0

Comment: If you could give us an example of your A matrix, a and b array, and the expected output, it could help us to quickly understand your question and avoid misguiding you.

Comment: Thanks, have edited it.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but isn't B([2,3],1) = [1,0]?